# React Native Local Image Load Times

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-image

I am relatively new to React Native, but enjoying it so far!

I'm currently using a FlatList to render some data. Each row of the FlatList uses a couple icons (.png) that are saved locally. They are pretty small, less than 100x100, but when I load up the app, there is a delay in the images being rendered.

Why is this? This wouldn't occur on a native iOS application, so how do I achieve it in Reat Native.

EDIT:

This delay appears when use EXPO on my iPhone X, but does not seam to appear when using EXPO on the iOS simulator.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using EXPO, try Preloading your images with: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/preloading-and-caching-assets.html

Comment: Should I actually need to do this since its a local file?